# QueryParameter doesn't pick up values from a url

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've created a piece of ampscript that needs to post form data to SalesCloud. Everything works fine, however I'm not able to pass the utm parameters from this url https://cloud.e.mywebsite.com/test-form-prod?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=whitepaper&utm_content=form. I'm using the following script:

```
SET @UTM_Source = QueryParameter('utm_source') 
SET @UTM_Medium = QueryParameter('utm_medium') 
SET @UTM_Campaign = QueryParameter('utm_campaign') 
SET @UTM_Content = QueryParameter('utm_content')
```

And then in the CreateSalesforceObject the following rules (example)

```
SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
  "Lead", 4,

    "UTMSource__c", @UTM_Source,
      "UTMMedium__c", @UTM_Medium,
      "UTMContent__c", @UTM_Content,
      "UTMCampaign__c", @UTM_Campaign)
```

For some reason it's not generating the parameters I have defined. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit: Complete code**

```
%%[
/* form submission check */
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN

/* UTM Parameters */
SET @originId = "request-quote"
SET @UTM_Source = QueryParameter('utm_source') 
SET @UTM_Medium = QueryParameter('utm_medium') 
SET @UTM_Campaign = QueryParameter('utm_campaign') 
SET @UTM_Content = QueryParameter('utm_content') 
SET @UTM_Term = QueryParameter('utm_term') 

/* check if account already exists */
SET @accountRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
  "Account",
  "Id,Name",
  "Name", "=", RequestParameter("company")
  )

/* get account id if contact already exists */
IF RowCount(@accountRows) > 0 THEN
SET @accountId = Field(Row(@accountRows, 1), "Id")
ENDIF

/* set consent checkbox */
IF RequestParameter("consent") == "on" THEN
SET @consent = "true"
ELSE SET @consent = "false"
ENDIF

/* check if contact already exists */
SET @contactRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
  "Contact",
  "Id,Email",
  "Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")
  )

SET @leadRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
  "Lead",
  "Id,Email",
  "Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")
  )

/* get contact id if contact already exists*/
IF RowCount(@contactRows) > 0 THEN
SET @contactId = Field(Row(@contactRows, 1), "Id")

/* update contact if already exists*/
SET @updateContactRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
  "Contact", @contactId,
  "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
  "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
  "AccountId", @accountId,
  "Phone", RequestParameter("phone"),
  "Country__c", RequestParameter("country"),
  "Industry__c", RequestParameter("industry"),
  "Role_in_the_buying_process__c", RequestParameter("role"),
  "CompanySize__c", RequestParameter("companysize"),
  "HasOptedInForEmail__c", @consent,
  "ContactOriginID__c", @originId,
  "Email", RequestParameter("email")
     )

/* update lead if already exists*/
ELSEIF RowCount(@leadRows) > 0 THEN
SET @leadId = Field(Row(@leadRows, 1), "Id")
SET @updateLeadRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
  "Lead", @leadId,
  "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
  "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
  "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
  "Email", RequestParameter("email"),
  "Phone", RequestParameter("phone"),
  "Country__c", RequestParameter("country"),
  "State__c", RequestParameter("state"),
  "LeadIndustry__c", RequestParameter("industry"),
  "RoleInTheBuyingProcess__c", RequestParameter("jobrole"),
  "CompanySize__c", RequestParameter("companysize"),
  "HasOptedInForEmail__c", @consent,
  "LeadOriginId__c", @originId
  )


/* create lead */
ELSE SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(
  "Lead", 16,
  "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),
  "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),
  "Company", RequestParameter("company"),
  "Email", RequestParameter("email"),
  "Phone", RequestParameter("phone"),
  "Country__c", RequestParameter("country"),
  "State__c", RequestParameter("state"),
  "LeadIndustry__c", RequestParameter("industry"),
  "RoleInTheBuyingProcess__c", RequestParameter("role"),
  "CompanySize__c", RequestParameter("companysize"),
  "HasOptedInForEmail__c", @consent,
  "LeadOriginId__c", @originId,
  "UTMSource__c", @UTM_Source,
  "UTMMedium__c", @UTM_Medium,
  "UTMContent__c", @UTM_Content,
  "UTMCampaign__c", @UTM_Campaign
  )

ENDIF


]%%
```

**Form**

```
<h2>Thank you for submitting the form.</h2>

%%[ ELSE ]%%

HTML form

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

**I've also tried this, but no luck**

```
"UTMSource__c", RequestParameter('utm_source'),
  "UTMMedium__c", RequestParameter('utm_source'),
  "UTMContent__c", RequestParameter('utm_source'),
  "UTMCampaign__c", RequestParameter('utm_source')
```

Comment: Have you tried request parameter?

Comment: @SwatiMishra, yes I did! I tried both, but I got the same result

Comment: Hi Daan - what is exactly happening, the lead doesn’t get created, or it does get created with blank fields? It seems that you are trying to create a lead with just 4 custom fields, and a standard Lead has some other mandatory fields. Maybe you could share more code for context?

Comment: @zuzannamj, I have added the complete code. This code is used with a form on a landingpage. I can confirm that all fields are visible in Sales Cloud after submission, just not the utm fields.

Comment: It looks like you are missing an endif statement in your code.  You never terminate the first if statement `IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN`. Technically this should toss a syntax error, but if it is not, that may be a cause for the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Gortonington, sorry, I've updated my question with my form code where you will see the ELSE and ENDIF

Comment: Ok two more questions: 1. How are you testing it? Are you actually redirecting from an email to the CloudPage? 2. Have you tried outputting the parameter values, eg. `Output(QueryParameter('utm_source'))`? That should tell you whether the problem is within the query function or later in the script

Comment: 1. I'm redirecting from an email from my personal account without any other parameters. This link directs to a cloudpage. 
2. I just tried the output and that shows the value newsletter for the source. So it seems to be in the script I think.

Comment: @zuzannamj, all other outputs also show the value from the parameters

Comment: I am running out of ideas... can you double check the UTM field API names in Salesforce? Check to see how those fields are set up in Salesforce? Maybe your MC Connect API user doesn’t have access to them?

Comment: @zuzannamj, thanks for thinking with me. I checked the API fields and those are correct. I performed a test where I place the values in the SET for each parameter and those come in correctly. So the following scenario is happening:

1. Output works: it shows the values from the url
2. Hardcoding the values works. API names are correct
3. The combination of queryparameter doesn't work. 

I will contact my website admin and salesforce support to see if they have any ideas.

Comment: btw your script seems to be missing an `ENDIF` at the very end, I don't think that is causing the problem you described..

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to the Salesforce Support and we came up with the following solution. After the submit the variables for the UTM parameters weren't being generated in time. To fix this the following hidden form:

```
<input name="utm_source" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@UTM_Source)=%%"><br>
<input name="utm_medium" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@UTM_Medium)=%%"><br>
<input name="utm_campaign" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@UTM_Campaign)=%%"><br>
<input name="utm_content" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@UTM_Content)=%%"><br>
```

This fixed the issue.

Thanks for all the help!